# .NET error 407 al consumir un servicio en visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, webservice, visual-studio-2019

Buenas tengo un problema al tratar de levantar una app .NET que consume un servicio,este el el codigo donde falla:

```
public WsGeocode()
        {
            geocode = new Geocode.Geocode();
            geocode.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constantes.AppSettings.WebServiceGeocode];
            string error = null;
            geocode.Init(ref error);
        }
```

el error es:

```
 System.Net.WebException: 'Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 407: Proxy Authentication Required.'
```

*Probe la url del servicio con otra app como SOAPUI y pude consumirlo, por lo que funciona. Pero no me funciona en .NET
*Tengo el Proxy de windows desactivado y a esa url accedo de una vpn interna, que es como probe con SOAP.